# Transfer file out from HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, data-transfer

I want to transfer files out from HDFS to local filesystem of a different server which is not in hadoop cluster but in the network.

I could have done:

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal <src> <dest>
and then scp/ftp <toMyFileServer>.
```

As the data is huge and due to limited space on local filesystem of hadoop gateway machine, I wanted to avoid this and sent data directly to my file server.

Please help with some pointers on how to handle this issue.

Comment: Could your fileserver connect directly to your namenode?

Comment: No. For now, It doesn't connect. But i would like to know your suggestion.

Comment: Would do a simple SSH tunnel to your namenode and connect from your fileserver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you probably have a file with a bunch of parts as the output from your hadoop program.

```
part-r-00000
part-r-00001
part-r-00002
part-r-00003
part-r-00004
```

So lets do one part at a time?

```
for i in `seq 0 4`;
do
hadoop fs -copyToLocal output/part-r-0000$i ./
scp ./part-r-0000$i you@somewhere:/home/you/
rm ./part-r-0000$i
done
```

You may have to lookup the password modifier for scp

Comment: What is you@someWhere is this command ,  Is that user_id and password for that windows shared path ?

Comment: username and server name for a linux machine. Where I might also SSH

ssh dciborow@myLinuxVM.azure.net

Answer (score 13):

This is the simplest way to do it:

```
ssh <YOUR_HADOOP_GATEWAY> "hdfs dfs -cat <src_in_HDFS> " > <local_dst>
```

It works for binary files too.

Comment: Is it possible to do it recursively? to copy files and directories?

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of webHDFS REST API to do that. Do a `curl` from the machine where you want to download the files.

```
curl -i -L "http://namenode:50075/webhdfs/v1/path_of_the_file?op=OPEN" -o ~/destination
```

Another approach could be to use the `DataNode API` through `wget` to do this :

```
wget http://$datanode:50075/streamFile/path_of_the_file
```

But, the most convenient way, IMHO, would be to use the NameNOde webUI. Since this machine is part of the network, you could just point your web browser to `NameNode_Machine:50070`. After that browse through the HDFS, open the file you want to download and click `Download this file`.

Answer (score 2):

I think simplest solution would be network mount or SSHFS to simulate local file server directory locally. 
You also can mount FTP as a local directory: 
http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/03/mount-ftp-server-linux.html

Comment: Thanks David for the solution! But, somehow cross environment mount is not available in here. I will go with workaround what djc391 has suggested for now.

Comment: You mentioned huge data, so I looked for the way to entirely avoid storing data locally.What you mean by cross environment mount?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do this too (I was using Kerberos security). This helped me after small update: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#OPEN

Run directly `curl -L -i --negotiate "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=OPEN"` didn't worked for me, I'll explain why.

This command will do two steps:

1. find a file you want to download and create a temporary link - return `307 Temporary Redirect`
2. from this link he will download a data - return `HTTP 200 OK`.

The switcher `-L` is saying that he take a file and continue with sawing directly. If you add to curl command `-v`, it'll log to output; if so, you'll see described two steps in command line, as I said. BUT - because due to older version curl (which I cannot udpate) it won't work.

SOLUTION FOR THIS (in Shell):

```
LOCATION=`curl -i --negotiate -u : "${FILE_PATH_FOR_DOWNLOAD}?op=OPEN" | /usr/bin/perl -n -e '/^Location: (.*)$/ && print "$1\n"'`
```

This will get temporary link and save it to `$LOCATION` variable.

```
RESULT=`curl -v -L --negotiate -u : "${LOCATION}" -o ${LOCAL_FILE_PATH_FOR_DOWNLOAD}`
```

And this will save it to your local file, if you add `-o <file-path>`.

I hope it helped.

J.