# how to copy hdfs files to another server [linux]

Tags: linux, hdfs

Is there a command avaialble to copy the files from `HDFS` to another `linux` box.

The Cluster is secured one.

I hope the `copyToLocal` will copy the files inside the cluster, actually i wanted to copy files outside the cluster.

Comment: This post shows how to use scp to transfer from HDFS, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173715/transfer-file-out-from-hdfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use WebHDFS to copy the file to your local machine. See for example here: http://hortonworks.com/blog/webhdfs-%E2%80%93-http-rest-access-to-hdfs/.

Since your cluster is secured (I suppose using Kerberos), you will need to get a Kerberos ticket (with `kinit`), and add flags like: `-udummy:dummy --negotiate` to your curl command.

Comment: Thanks @Hellmar Becker : i will try this, thanks for kinit and flag level details.